# Using flash spark videoplayer component for pseudostreaming

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video-player

I am developing an app that requires pseudostreaming and live streaming. So we have done many test with flash and jwplayer.  I really like jwplayer because it works for both pseudostreaming and live streaming (rmtp), and the cool thing is that it has html5. But the problem is that in our app we might have many streams at the same time and we want a single interface to handle that.  We are still trying to figure out how to that with jwplayer.  But in the mean time I was trying to do this directly with flash/flex  and AS3 directly and I saw there is a VideoPlayer component, and I was wondering if it supports pseudostreaming.
How do I point it at my file.  Would I be able to fastforward with the controls? 
My webserver is properly configured and the pseudostreaming works with jwplayer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the VideoPlayer supports video streaming and progressive download ("pseudostreaming"). Just set the source property to the location of your video file. Example:

```
<s:VideoPlayer 
  source="http://yourserver.com/video.f4v"
  width="75%" height="75%"
  autoPlay="false"
  loop="true"/>
```

Comment: I'm new here; can anybody help me understand why my answer was downvoted? I answered the question and provided example mxml.

Comment: I dont know man I upvoted it, i wanted to be sure that progressive download is the same as pseudostreaming, thanks

Comment: apparently pseudo-streaming is no the same as progressive downloading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746101/flash-flex-progressive-download-vs-rtmp